# Thought experiment: Argument whose life is more valuable organic or mechanical?

Tags: argumentation, artificial-intelligence, life

Let's consider the following scenario:

There is a really important mission consisting of a team of two individuals: a sentient, artificially intelligent robot and a human. If the mission fails, both individuals die, however, the mission can succeed if one of the individuals sacrifices himself. Both individuals can perform same duties required equally to complete the mission, and both have an equally strong desire to live.

Given this scenario:
The human could argue:

- that he is living and therefore cannot be remade as robot in factory.
- that he has relatives that are waiting for him.
- that robot is not going to feel pain or human emotion while dying.

**What reasons could robot (AI) give to be on par with human to be kept alive?**

Comment: Can you share a little bit more about what you might have been reading that may have made this an important or interesting question in your study of philosophy?

Comment: @JosephWeissman Why are you asking?

Comment: To try to persuade you to share a little bit more about the context and motivations of the problem you're encountering

Comment: Why are you looking for context and motivation? How is it relevant?

Comment: Briefly -- I'm worried this may open up discussion on somewhat too broad/vague a theme; is there any chance you could help delimit this a bit, maybe share a little bit about the context and motivations of the question (what might have made this interesting/important to you; what you've hypothesized/discovered so far)? Keep in mind SE is optimized for narrowly-focused questions that have *one* answer; at any rate, it might help optimize your chances of getting a great answer to zoom in on some *particular* concern that has come up in your reading or study.

Comment: In what aspect you think this should be narrowed down? Which part of it is vague? To avoid conversations and going of topic, and to optimize my chances of getting an answer I am looking for I gave examples of answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15290/discussion-between-joseph-weissman-and-liufa).

Answer (score 4):

I think the situation your are presenting doesn't make sense. Let's take the military as an example. Being in some combat military units would involve taking substantial risks that you might die. The people who go into such units are aware of the risk and have chosen to take it.  For any job that carries similar risk, the people doing it should know about the risk and choose to take it. So it is not the case that the people concerned necessarily want to live unconditionally.

If the commanding officer of such a unit judges that some task carries a particularly high risk he has to judge who to assign to that task and will have some reason for whatever decision he takes. The person assigned to that task could argue he should not be assigned to it. It is impossible to specify all of the arguments that a person might give as to why he should not be assigned to a task. Such arguments would depend on lots of details of the context, not all of which are about the person or the task or even the unit itself. For example, a soldier might say he shouldn't be assigned to Task Certain Death because he has children and other people who can do it don't have children.

I don't see that it makes any difference whether the person in question is made of meat, i.e. - a human as opposed to an AI. The solution to any realistic problem will depend on lots of stuff other than being made of meat.

Comment: Hi alanf, having children and relatives is very valid argument to send machine to die, and this is the type of argumentation I am looking for. I haven't added much detail on purpose as question would then become 'on who is better fit to do the job specified', and not 'who should live because he is more useful or deserving (for reasons like having relatives) to live'.

Comment: Who says an AI couldn't have a child? Ever heard of adoption? Also, not having created AI we don't know how it's going to work so maybe AIs will be able to have children.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting!

Above all, the mission must be of enough importance to have to make this decision. This is a separate question in itself.
Once the mission is important enough:

- If they can both complete the mission just as well; human wins.
- If the mission is beyond human's capabilities; machine wins.

Comment: Could you expand on reasoning why human wins over machine in situation there both are capable to complete the mission?

Comment: It is because once the mission is over, the machine becomes redundant when its use is over. The human is adaptable to `post-mission` circumstances. This `usability beyond the mission` is where the human trumps the machine. Once machines become more advanced to adapt to circumstances, human usability `post-mission` usability comes into question.

Answer (score 1):

when it came to ensuring mission success, when making decisions like choosing between sacrificing number 1 (ryker) and number 2(data) captain picard would always do the mission himself (and sacrificed himself a few times but was always saved eventually)because he thought data's life was as valuable as anyone else, yet every crew member was always ready to sacrifice themselves at a moments notice, because mission success was more important than who lives and dies, because if no one sacrifices themselves, everybody dies. silly analogy, i know, but star trek always provides insightful thought experiments on leadership. in the immortal words of the mighty Spock; "logic dictates, that the needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few".

i think this would be closer to the truth;

commanders prerogative, during wartime i think the commander would make the decision based on utility and necessity, or how valuable the human or robot would be for future missions, which i think would negate either robot or humans arguments for declining mission. this makes the sacrifice the human as i assume the robot is intellectually and physically superior to the human, thus more valuable in its utility. generally in wartime (or any special mission) necessity is the dictator of action, and a decision based on utility would be most consistent with necessity

Comment: Let's consider that commander is indispensable in given situation (he's not Kirk), who should live and who should die then?

Comment: commanders prerogative, during wartime i think the commander would make the decision based on utility and necessity, or how valuable the human or robot would be for future missions, which i think would negate either robot or humans arguments for declining mission. this makes the sacrifice the human as i assume the robot is intellectually and physically superior to the human, thus more valuable in its utility. generally in wartime (or any special mission) necessity is the dictator of action, and a decision based on utility would be most consistent with necessity.